# Are there differences between academic papers and industrial papers?

Tags: publications, industry, literature

Are there differences between academic papers (f.e. a (conference) paper written by PhD students and/or professors) and industrial papers (f.e. a conference paper written by engineers working for a company)?

Comment: Good question... Welcome to Academia.SX and thank you.

Comment: Many papers can be both.  I have one as first author when I was in a university, with industrial collaborators, and one as a lowly co-author from when I was in industry, where the lead author was academic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am a scientist working in a company and frequently collaborating with university academics.  There is no difference between the papers we write.

People at companies are more likely to write more applied papers, and people at universities are more likely to write more theoretical papers, but the distributions are highly overlapping.